# How to filter Fiddler traffic by request method?

Tags: fiddler, http-method

Fiddler is capturing a lot of HTTP OPTIONS calls, which I have no interest in.

Is it possible to ignore these and only see GET and POST?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In Fiddler, click "Rules" --> "Customize Rules".  This will open a script file allowing you to create custom rules.

#### If you want to hide all OPTIONS requests

find `OnBeforeRequest` and add in this code:

```
static function OnBeforeRequest(oSession: Session) {
    if (oSession.HTTPMethodIs("OPTIONS")) {
       oSession["ui-hide"] = "true";
    }
```

#### Or alternatively, if you want to hide them only once they have returned 200

find `OnBeforeResponse` and add in this code:

```
static function OnBeforeResponse(oSession: Session) {
    if (oSession.HTTPMethodIs("OPTIONS") && oSession.responseCode == 200) {
       oSession["ui-hide"] = "true";
    }
```

Comment: I added a little to this with `if (oSession.HTTPMethodIs("OPTIONS") && oSession.responseCode != 200) { oSession["ui-hide"] = "false"; }` inside `OnBeforeResponse` so I can see the any strange option responses.

Comment: @WORMSS I like that a lot.  I've added something similar to my answer now, which I think is a slight improvement again.  With this third version, if a OPTIONS call is slow & hanging then you will be able to see what is happening.  (Rather then just empty window for 20 seconds before it finally errors.)